# Performance Issues with React.js Website Using SSR and WordPress Backend on EC2 Server

Tags: reactjs, performance, optimization, server-side-rendering

I have developed a React.js website with SSR (Server-Side Rendering), and the backend is powered by WordPress. While the site loads smoothly in the localhost within 8 seconds, it takes nearly 30 seconds after deploying it on an EC2 server. Additionally, the performance score on the desktop is only 30, falling short of the desired score of 60 or higher.

I am seeking guidance on optimizing the website's performance to reduce the initial loading time and improve the overall performance score. Here are some key details:

Localhost Performance:

Loading time: 8 seconds
Performance score: NA
EC2 Server Performance:

Loading time: 30 seconds
Performance score: 30 on desktop
Expectations:

Loading time should be significantly reduced on the EC2 server.
Aim for a performance score of 60 or higher on desktop.
Environment:

React.js with SSR
WordPress backend
Deployed on an EC2 server
Steps Already Taken:

Utilized SSR for server-side rendering.
Configured the website with WordPress as the backend.
Request for Assistance:

Any insights into why the EC2 deployment is causing slower loading times?
Strategies to optimize the React.js SSR setup on an EC2 server.
Tips for improving the performance score, especially on desktop.
Thank you for your assistance!

Implemented server-side rendering (SSR) in React.js to enhance initial loading performance.
Configured the website to use WordPress as the backend.
Deployed the application on an EC2 server.
Analyzed the performance using tools like Lighthouse or PageSpeed Insights.
Investigated server logs and network requests for potential bottlenecks.
Experimented with caching mechanisms to optimize data retrieval from WordPress.
Expectations:

Anticipated that SSR and proper backend integration would contribute to faster loading times.
Expected a performance score of at least 60 on desktop based on local testing.
Actual Results:

Loading time on EC2 server is approximately 30 seconds, significantly higher than the localhost (8 seconds).
Performance score on desktop is only 30, falling short of the expected target.
Request for Guidance:

Seeking insights on potential reasons for the slower loading times on the EC2 server.
Recommendations for further optimizations in the React.js SSR setup.
Strategies to improve the overall performance score, especially on the desktop.